# Create a subtitle in navigationbar

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationbar

In iOS you can create a title with:

```
self.navBar.title = @"";
```

where I set navBar in the header file.

Is there also something for the subTitle / Description?

I found `description` when I typed a `.` after `self.navBar` and thought maybe I could do something with this?

Comment: Description is on every NSObject. It returns the object description (members values, memory address etc.).

Comment: It will help you all existing scenario https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37409260/uilabel-text-truncation-vs-line-breaks-in-text

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `self.navBar.navigationItem.prompt = @"This is the subtitle";`

It's from UIKit in the base UINavigationViewController.

Comment: Is there a way to put it in the "normal" viewController? Since it worked for the normal title?

Comment: Do it like to do it for the the title but target the navigationItem. It's standard.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C code for the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38628080/4168785)

```
UILable *title = [[UILabel alloc]init];
UILabel *subtitle = [[UILabel alloc]init];

[title setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
[title setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[title setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17]];
[title sizeToFit];
title.text = @"Title";

[subtitle setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[subtitle setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
[subtitle setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[subtitle sizeToFit];
subtitle.text = @"Subtitle Title";

UIStackView *stackVw = [[UIStackView alloc]initWithArrangedSubviews:@[title,subtitle]];
stackVw.distribution = UIStackViewDistributionEqualCentering;
stackVw.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical;
stackVw.alignment =UIStackViewAlignmentCenter;


[stackVw setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, MAX(title.frame.size.width, subtitle.frame.size.width), 35)];
self.navigationItem.titleView = stackVw;
```