# UILabel text truncation vs. line breaks in text

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uinavigationbar

I have a `UILabel` that is put as titleView in the navigation bar. I want it to have 2 lines, where the first line can be truncated and the second is center aligned.

In code it looks more less like this:

```
    let label = UILabel()
    let text = NSAttributedString(string: "Long long long text\nsecond line")
    label.attributedText = text
    label.textAlignment = .Center
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = .ByTruncatingTail
    label.sizeToFit()

    self.navigationItem.titleView = label
```

> The effect in case of the first line text is not exceeding available
>   space is like this:

[image]

> It's pretty good, but when the first line text is longer than:

```
let text = NSAttributedString(string: "Very very very very very long text\nsecond line")
```

[image]

> I want to achieve like below.

[image]

How it can be done? I experimented with numberOfLines and lineBreakMode but it's not worked.

Comment: Why do not you use UIView with two UILabels inside?

Comment: Using two labels make a lot of problems in positioning them, believe me. Two labels was my first shot but it's very problematic so I decided to try with one label instead.

Comment: lineBreakMode is the property applied for the whole content, not applicable for every single line. So you must have to go with two UILabels. What are all the issues you've faced in two labels?

Answer (score 1):

change your line breakmode to `ByTruncatingMiddle` instead of `ByTruncatingTail`. Something like below,

```
    label.lineBreakMode = .ByTruncatingMiddle
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: No, it doesn't work too. Effect is the same as for ByTruncatingTail.

Comment: try to comment `label.sizeToFit()` with `ByTruncatingMiddle` linebreakmode

Comment: commenting out sizeToFit causes that the label is no longer visible because its frame is not set

Comment: try to set frame of label to `self.navigationItem.titleView.frame` and then comment sizetofit

Comment: you can use `minimumFontSize` to resize font to adjust in label if you have not problem if font size is reduce little bit.

Comment: I can't set the frame of titleView manually because I don't know what is the available space between back button and rightBarButtonItem.

Comment: using minimumFontSize is not solution for me, I want it to be fixed size

Answer (score 1):

**Navigation Tittle with sub-Tittle (Multiline Navigation Tittle)**

Use NSMutableAttributedString with **UITextView** instead of **UILabel**

(because, if **tittle** is **large** then **UILabel** lineBreakMode with .byTruncatingTail is **not working for first line** in UILabel)

```
func multilineNavigation(title:String,subTitle:String) {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let titleAttributedStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: title, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.orange,NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 17.0) ?? UIFont()])
        let subTitleAttributedStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\n\(subTitle)", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.green,NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 12.0) ?? UIFont()])
        titleAttributedStr.append(subTitleAttributedStr)

        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 1
        paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail

        titleAttributedStr.addAttribute(.paragraphStyle, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, titleAttributedStr.length))

        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.attributedText = titleAttributedStr
        textView.backgroundColor = .clear
        textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        textView.textContainerInset = .zero
        textView.textAlignment = .center
        textView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: textView.intrinsicContentSize.width, height: 44)

        self.navigationItem.titleView = textView
    }
}
```