# Add subtitle under the title in navigation bar controller in Xcode

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

So I'm wanting to add a "subtitle" under the title in the navigation bar in navigation controller.

Mostly everything I look up so far wants me to use CGRect. I don't know a whole lot what that is and it sounds like its wanting me to create an entire new view which is not what I am wanting to do.

My question is, is there a dot method to adding a subtitle view easily?

The closest thing I found was posted on stack overflow and here is the link:

[Create a subtitle in navigationbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29626710/create-a-subtitle-in-navigationbar)

Apparently last year this worked but now I am getting errors and it's in my viewDidLoad...

I tried this:

self.navigationController?.navigationItem.prompt = "Subtitle Here"

It's the only thing that won't show any errors but still doesn't work. It literally does nothing. At least nothing visible at run time.

On a side note, swift is preferred. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `self.navigationItem.prompt = "Subtitle"`?

Comment: @tktsubota That will make the subtitle above title and not below title

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari Yeah I did a test and found that out.

Comment: @tktsubota are you joking? It's not subtitle, it's a new separate bar above navigation bar with its own title, this way you have two bars, useless!

Comment: It will help you all existing scenario https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37409260/uilabel-text-truncation-vs-line-breaks-in-text

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Though there is a solution but it has some known issues

Solution is writing a function like this

```
func setTitle(title:String, subtitle:String) -> UIView {
    let titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, -2, 0, 0))

    titleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    titleLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(17)
    titleLabel.text = title
    titleLabel.sizeToFit()

    let subtitleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 18, 0, 0))
    subtitleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    subtitleLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    subtitleLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12)
    subtitleLabel.text = subtitle
    subtitleLabel.sizeToFit()

    let titleView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, max(titleLabel.frame.size.width, subtitleLabel.frame.size.width), 30))
    titleView.addSubview(titleLabel)
    titleView.addSubview(subtitleLabel)

    let widthDiff = subtitleLabel.frame.size.width - titleLabel.frame.size.width

    if widthDiff < 0 {
        let newX = widthDiff / 2
        subtitleLabel.frame.origin.x = abs(newX)
    } else {
        let newX = widthDiff / 2
        titleLabel.frame.origin.x = newX
    }

    return titleView
}
```

Using this function for custom navigation title view in `viewDidLoad`

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = setTitle("Title", subtitle: "SubTitle")
```

Only known issue is that if subtitle becomes very large than the misplacement occurs.

Final Outcome
[image]

Source: https://gist.github.com/nazywamsiepawel/0166e8a71d74e96c7898

Comment: Its a whole lot more code then i was expecting but it does work. I really hope Apple adds an easier way. Subtitle doesn't seem like anything that would be so far fetched.. lol

Comment: Thanks a ton by the way! :) @rajan

Comment: I need something like this, If title is blank then title should in center. I have to implement in chat app. If user starts typing, then subtitle show. For more see whatsApp.

Comment: title and subtitle slide to centre from left when pushing from navigation controller any workarounds  @naveed

Comment: above solution work for centering the both text, in my case its working

Comment: Having the same issue as @Zoom, from other posts it looks like it may be related to when in the view lifecycle the title is updated?

Comment: @Yasir adding the code for title and subtitle in viewDidAppear worked for me.

Comment: My issue was fixed, keeping the initial update coming async from viewDidLoad. It was setting the titleView to an attributed label multiple times as the content changed during transition in. Got it working by only setting the view once, then only updating its contents if already present.

Comment: how can i change alignment of both above to be left only

Comment: i tried 
        titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
but not working for me

Comment: I want to text alignment at left, is it possible ?

Answer (score 83):

Here is my version using a stack view on an extension.

```
extension UINavigationItem {
    func setTitle(title:String, subtitle:String) {
        
        let one = UILabel()
        one.text = title
        one.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)
        one.sizeToFit()
        
        let two = UILabel()
        two.text = subtitle
        two.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
        two.textAlignment = .center
        two.sizeToFit()
        
        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [one, two])
        stackView.distribution = .equalCentering
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.alignment = .center
        
        let width = max(one.frame.size.width, two.frame.size.width)
        stackView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: 35)
        
        one.sizeToFit()
        two.sizeToFit()
        
        self.titleView = stackView
    }
}
```

Comment: title and subtitle slide to centre from left when pushing from navigation controller any workarounds

Comment: To me, this is the cleaner answer, it doesn't have magic numbers as the first answer. I will only add `stackView.alignment = .center` after you set the axis, otherwise it will not appear totally centered if the subtitle is bigger.

Also I would remove the last two calls to `sizeToFit()`, since you called them on the labels.

Comment: does default title also has constant font value 17?

Answer (score 16):

@iosjillian's Swift 4 extension works great, adding a bit more to honor the bar's appearance and user font preferences:

```
import UIKit

extension UINavigationItem {

  func setTitle(_ title: String, subtitle: String) {
    let appearance = UINavigationBar.appearance()
    let textColor = appearance.titleTextAttributes?[NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor] as? UIColor ?? .black

    let titleLabel = UILabel()
    titleLabel.text = title
    titleLabel.font = .preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFont.TextStyle.headline)
    titleLabel.textColor = textColor

    let subtitleLabel = UILabel()
    subtitleLabel.text = subtitle
    subtitleLabel.font = .preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFont.TextStyle.subheadline)
    subtitleLabel.textColor = textColor.withAlphaComponent(0.75)

    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [titleLabel, subtitleLabel])
    stackView.distribution = .equalCentering
    stackView.alignment = .center
    stackView.axis = .vertical

    self.titleView = stackView
  }
}
```

Comment: Not working on iOS 16

Answer (score 11):

Thanks a lot for your answer! @RajanMaheshwari

Your coding worked perfectly except the if statement you made with the widthDiff..

I adjusted it a little bit and everything worked smoothly.

```
if widthDiff < 0 {
        let newX = widthDiff / 2
        subtitleLabel.frame.origin.x = abs(newX)
    } else {
        let newX = widthDiff / 2
        titleLabel.frame.origin.x = newX
    }
```

Thanks again for your response!

Comment: Great fix! Had to do this as well.

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone looking for `Objective-C` code of the above mentioned solution:

```
   UILabel *title = [[UILabel alloc]init];
   UILabel *subtitle = [[UILabel alloc]init];

   [title setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
   [title setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
   [title setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17]];
   [title sizeToFit];
   title.text = @"Title";

   [subtitle setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
   [subtitle setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
   [subtitle setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
   [subtitle sizeToFit];
   subtitle.text = @"Subtitle Title";

   UIStackView *stackVw = [[UIStackView alloc]initWithArrangedSubviews:@[title,subtitle]];
   stackVw.distribution = UIStackViewDistributionEqualCentering;
   stackVw.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical;
   stackVw.alignment =UIStackViewAlignmentCenter;


   [stackVw setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, MAX(title.frame.size.width, subtitle.frame.size.width), 35)];
   self.navigationItem.titleView = stackVw;
```

Answer (score 5):

I really liked @user2325031's answer, but found that sizing the labels to fit and setting the frame wasn't needed. I also set the stackView's alignment to .center per @GerardoMR's suggestion.

```
extension UINavigationItem {

    func setTitle(_ title: String, subtitle: String) {
        let titleLabel = UILabel()
        titleLabel.text = title
        titleLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 17.0)
        titleLabel.textColor = .black

        let subtitleLabel = UILabel()
        subtitleLabel.text = subtitle
        subtitleLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 12.0)
        subtitleLabel.textColor = .gray

        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [titleLabel, subtitleLabel])
        stackView.distribution = .equalCentering
        stackView.alignment = .center
        stackView.axis = .vertical

        self.titleView = stackView
    }

}
```

Comment: Now working on iOS 16

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the answer @RajanMaheshwari

If anyone is having the issue where the title becomes misaligned when the subtitle text is longer than the title text, I added the following code to the Rajan's answer above just below where the subtitleLabel is instantiated:

```
// Fix incorrect width bug
if (subtitleLabel.frame.size.width > titleLabel.frame.size.width) {
    var titleFrame = titleLabel.frame
    titleFrame.size.width = subtitleLabel.frame.size.width
    titleLabel.frame = titleFrame
    titleLabel.textAlignment = .center
}
```

Hope this helps someone who encountered the same issue as me

Comment: as per @GerardoMR comment above -- you can center title/subtitle using the UIStackView setting:  `stackView.alignment = .center`

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, using only *one* label and `NSAttributedString` to differentiate between title and subtitle (with different font sizes, weights, colors, etc.) instead. Removes the problem of different label alignment.

```
extension UIViewController {
    func setTitle(_ title: String, subtitle: String) {
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 50)
        let titleSize: CGFloat = 20     // adjust as needed
        let subtitleSize: CGFloat = 15

        let label = UILabel(frame: rect)
        label.backgroundColor = .clear
        label.numberOfLines = 2
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.textColor = .black

        let text = NSMutableAttributedString()
        text.append(NSAttributedString(string: title, attributes: [.font : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: titleSize)]))
        text.append(NSAttributedString(string: "\n\(subtitle)", attributes: [.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: subtitleSize)]))
        label.attributedText = text
        self.navigationItem.titleView = label
    }
}
```

Custom titleView based in part on https://stackoverflow.com/a/34298491/3918865

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4:

```
import UIKit

class NavigationTitleView: UIView {

    private var contentStackView = UIStackView()
    private var titleLabel = UILabel()
    private var subTitleLabel = UILabel()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        viewConfig()
        addViewsConfig()
        layoutViewsConfig()

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    func set(title: String, subTitle: String){

        self.titleLabel.text = title
        self.subTitleLabel.text = subTitle

    }

    private func viewConfig() {

        contentStackView.axis = .vertical
        contentStackView.alignment = .center
        contentStackView.distribution  = .fill
        contentStackView.spacing = 5


        self.backgroundColor = .clear
        self.titleLabel.textColor = .white
        self.self.subTitleLabel.textColor = .white

    }

    private func addViewsConfig() {

        contentStackView.addArrangedSubview(subTitleLabel)
        contentStackView.addArrangedSubview(titleLabel)
        self.addSubview(contentStackView)

    }

    private func layoutViewsConfig(){

        contentStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentStackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        contentStackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true

    }

}
```

Use:

```
import UIKit

class  ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var navigationTitleView = NavigationTitleView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationItem.titleView = navigationTitleView
        navigationTitleView.set(title: "title", subTitle: "subTitle")

    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Easy fix for iOS 16. Following the @iosjillian's / @Dan's approx, calling layoutSubviews() on stack view does the trick.

```js
extension UINavigationItem {

    func setTitle(_ title: String, subtitle: String) {
        
        let textColor = getTextColor()
        
        let titleLabel = UILabel()
        titleLabel.text = title
        titleLabel.font = .preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFont.TextStyle.headline)
        titleLabel.textColor = textColor

        let subtitleLabel = UILabel()
        subtitleLabel.text = subtitle
        subtitleLabel.font = .preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFont.TextStyle.subheadline)
        subtitleLabel.textColor = textColor.withAlphaComponent(0.75)

        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [titleLabel, subtitleLabel])
        stackView.distribution = .equalCentering
        stackView.alignment = .center
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.layoutSubviews()
               
        self.titleView = stackView
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Working **iOS 16** solution. **Swift 5.7**

With SnapKit library. If you are not using SnapKit lib, just make both views (titleLabel and subtitleLabel) translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false and replace SnapKit Constraints with native constraints.

```
func setTitle(title: String, subtitle: String, view: UIView) -> UIView {
    let appearance = UINavigationBar.appearance()
    let titleColor = appearance.titleTextAttributes?[NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor] as? UIColor ?? .black

    let titleLabel = UILabel()

    titleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    titleLabel.textColor = titleColor
    titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = false
    titleLabel.font = .preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFont.TextStyle.headline)
    titleLabel.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
    titleLabel.textAlignment = .center
    titleLabel.text = title
    
    let subtitleLabel = UILabel()
    subtitleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    subtitleLabel.textColor = UIColor.init(hexString: "#808890")
    subtitleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = false
    subtitleLabel.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
    subtitleLabel.textAlignment = .center
    subtitleLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 11)
    subtitleLabel.text = subtitle
    
    let titleView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 30))
    titleView.addSubview(titleLabel)
    titleView.addSubview(subtitleLabel)
    
    titleLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
        make.horizontalEdges.equalToSuperview()
        make.top.equalToSuperview().offset(-20)
        make.height.equalTo(20)
    }

    subtitleLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
        make.horizontalEdges.equalToSuperview()
        make.top.equalTo(titleLabel.snp.bottom).offset(4)
        make.height.equalTo(10)
    }
    
    
    
    return titleView
}
```