# Title and Subtitle on Large Navigation Bar Swift

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, ios11, preferslargetitles

I've seen similar posts on stack overflow, but haven't seen any specific to **large navigation bars** that change size as the user scrolls down.

What I would like to achieve is a left-aligned title and subtitle in my navigation bar that either hides or decreases in size the subtitle when converted to a regular navigation bar.

Other answers in SO such as this one: (https://stackoverflow.com/a/42400633/5476481), create custom views, but they are commonly unresponsive to movements in the bar.

[image]

Any ideas on how to properly achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

You can use custom navigation bar as a navigation bar and hide default navigation bar.[image]